# Can I dereference std::string.end()?

Tags: c++, string, language-lawyer, std

I believe a common response to this is "no," as the `end()` iterator for containers represents a "past-the-end" address which is undefined behavior to dereference. I can't find an explicit statement in the standard that exempts strings from this constraint, even though strings have a special case over other containers.

The C++11 standard declares that you can read one index past the end of a string. `string[size()]` references a read-only value of a null terminator.

> **24.3.2.5 basic_string element access [string.access]**
>
> `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`
>
> `reference operator[](size_type pos);`
>
> (1) *Requires:* `pos <= size()`.
>
> (2) *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos) if pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type
>   `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object to any value other than `charT()` leads to
>   undefined behavior.

`front()` is defined to be equivalent to `return operator[](0)` which is equivalent to `return operator[](size())` for an empty string.

`end() - begin()` is well-defined to be a difference of the length of the string, so `end()` must be pointing to the index of `size()` for a sane implementation to define that arithmetic.

In the above standard excerpt, it states that `operator[](pos)` is equivalent to `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. It does *not* say that you can dereference `begin() + size()`, but do you think it is reasonable to assume that this should be well defined? Or better yet, do you know of some proof that exempts string iterators from the constraint?

Additionally, can it be proven that `*(begin() + i)` for any `i` is equivalent to `operator[](i)`?

Comment: It is not legal to dereference the `end()` iterator of *any* container, including `std::string`. Logically, `end()` could refer to the string's null terminator, which C++11 requires to exist in memory. But `end()` is not required to refer to the *actual* null terminator in memory. The only requirement is that `operator[](size())` refer to "*an object of type `charT`*", which could just as easily be a static `char(0)` defined outside of the `string` object, which is important for implementations that store a `nullptr` `char*` pointer for empty strings. That doesn't change how `end()` behaves.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hence my note about 'sane' implementations. If `end()` is pointing to a static value away from the string memory, the implementation would require checking for this case all over the place just to handle simple things like `end() - 1` which should point to the last character in a string. I know it's illegal in general for any container, but maybe that should be rectified for strings? Question is if there is already proof of this that I can't find.

Comment: I would expect "sane" implementations to make `end()` point to the address of the null terminator to keep things simple. That still doesn't make `end()` legal to dereference, even if the memory backing it is valid. Making the `std::string::end()` iterator a special case that behaves differently than other containers would just complicate algorithms that are designed to act on *any* container. There is no good reason to *ever* dereference a `std::string::end()` iterator. So I don't think there is anything to "rectify" in the standard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `operator[](size())` is already a special case for string containers which is illegal for other containers. `string` has a special case where you can read one past the end; why would it not make sense to rectify the standard to make `end()` behave the same way?

Comment: @RemyLebeau [*Until C++11, `std::string` was not required to include a trailing nul until you called `c_str()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21245027/995714). Facebook for example has also implemented their own `std::string` without a null terminator: [The strange details of std::string at Facebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk&index=8&list=PLiDK46vnsTT-JerJ8k5-W5L-yKvSu0M41)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the definition of [string.end()](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.iterators#2):

> Returns: An iterator which is the **past-the-end** value.

and from the definition for [past-the-end](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#7):

> ... Such a value is called a past-the-end value. Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called dereferenceable. The library **never assumes** that past-the-end values are dereferenceable. ...

The emphasis is mine, and I would guess that any exception made for `std::string` would be mentioned in the first link. Since it's not, dereferencing `std::string.end()` is undefined by omission.

Comment: We could say it is undefined by omission, since there appears to be no clause which defines the behaviour of dereferencing it

Comment: @M.M I like that wording, thanks :) Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that in the case of `std::string` it should be possible since it it's stands to reason that it's a null-terminator, but it's still undefined behaviour:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end

> *Returns an iterator to the character following the last character of the string. This character acts as a placeholder, attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.*

In the strings library there is no reference I can find that points in either direction, however since we're talking about an iterator, the iterator library defines:

[©ISO/IECN4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) § 27.2.1 - 7

> *...for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence. These values are called past-the-end values...The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable...*

Comment: For a language-lawyer question it'd be nice to have citations to the standard, rather than an unofficial reference site.

Comment: While it is known that dereferencing past-the-end for containers in general is illegal/undefined, I think it's interesting that the standard does not explicitly state that here. It states that the library assumes that it is, i.e., the library will not do that. Does that rule out std::string having an end() iterator that is valid, irrelevant to the library's assumptions?

Comment: No, the standard *could* make an exception for `std::string`, but it doesn't. Also, the *never assumes* part would probably have to be changed.

Comment: @cigien: "*Also, the never assumes part would probably have to be changed.*" But you can pass a dereferenceable iterator as an end iterator for a range, and this will still be true. What it's describing is a prohibition on how the *library* will use end iterators, not on what end iterators actually are.

Comment: @mukunda, it's definitely interesting, but the assumption must be that it can't be done, maybe it was found that the reference in the iterators library was enough and there was no need to mention it in the strings library, The never assumes part leaves the door opened for implementation defined behaviour which is not uncomon.

Comment: @anastaciu I would say that the assumption is from it not having a use case, as well as being a strong assumption in general that past-the-end should not be read. There is no need to support that case in the library.

Comment: @mukunda, yes, well noted.