# Reverse a string C++

Tags: c++, string, char, reverse

I'm new to programming. I've learned how to reverse a string today. I've tried to use string instead of char but terminal gives an error.

```
string name = { "george" };
int nChar = sizeof(name) - 1;
string *pName = &name;
string *pNameLast = &name + nChar - 1;

while(pName < pNameLast) {
    string save = *pName;
    *pName = *pNameLast;
    *pNameLast = save;
    
    pName++;
    pNameLast--;
}

cout << name << endl;
```

[image]

Comment: please include the error in the question. Note that there is an algorithm `std::reverse`, I guess you want to go for the handwritten, right?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with `string *pNameLast = &name + nChar - 1;`? Do you know what that does? It seems like you just replaced every instance of `char` with `string`.

Comment: Hint - you cannot just replace `char*` with `std::string` and expect your code to work.

Comment: i understand. but how can i reverse it using a string? i don't really understand how it works :\

Comment: `sizeof(name)` will give you the size of the `std::string` object, which is *not* the same as the length of the string it wraps.

Comment: Check the value on `nChar`. Besides, instead of trying to use pointers, simply use `name[i]`...

Comment: I suggest you invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ properly. Perhaps even take a few classes.

Comment: In order to get to the pointer of the beginning of the array contained in string, `&name` should be replaced by `reinterpret_cast<void*>(name.data())` with c++11 (there is a 2 bytes difference).

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot there shouldnt be any `&name` in the code in the first place

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you reverse a string in place in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198199/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of using `std::reverse_interator`. This is better a better way of doing it. Rather than doing it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
 
int main()
{
    std::string s = "George";
    std::reverse_iterator<std::string::iterator> r = s.rbegin();
    std::string rev(r, s.rend());
    std::cout << rev << endl;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `rbegin` and `rend`, since right now you're dereferencing `end`.

Comment: Stephen Newell is right, it is giving me an extra space at the start that I suppose is from the [Undefined Behavior caused by dereferencing `std::string::end()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669762/can-i-dereference-stdstring-end).

Comment: @GaryNLOL You are right. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse a string object, just do the following (note this is the one of many handmade ways:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string my_string{"hello"};

    // Similar to your way:
    int index{static_cast<int>(my_string.length() - 1)};
    for (; index >= 0; --index) {
        std::cout << my_string.at(index) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: better don't call it `length` when it isnt the length but an index

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 true

Comment: Won't your loop condition always be true since `size_t` is unsigned, meaning it'll underflow when `index==0`?

Comment: Stephen Newell is right, it is underflowing. `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at:: __n (which is 18446744073709551615) >= this->size() (which is 5)`.

Comment: @StephenNewell that is true! I will change to a correct loop

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

When you attempt to do operations like `string *pName = &name` and
`string *pNameLast = &name + nChar - 1;`, you're treating `std::string`'s as `char*`'s. You cannot do that and expect the code to work.

**Solution:**

Treat `std::string`'s as `std::string`'s. Instead of doing `string *pName = &name` declare `pName` as an `int` and use the operator `[]` of `std::string` to access to the values. Similarly with `pNameLast`. You also have to declare `string save` as a `char` or, as I prefer, use the `std::swap` function.

**Additional info:**

1. As far as I can see you're probably using `using namespace std;` as you're declaring `std::string` as `string`. If that is the case consider that `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string name = "george";
    int length = name.size();
    int pNameFirst = 0;
    int pNameLast = length - 1;

    while(pNameFirst < pNameLast)
    {
        std::swap(name[pNameFirst],name[pNameLast]);

        pNameFirst++;
        pNameLast--;
    }
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: this is most accurate version. thank you :)